# Can't access windows after installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10.  Now unable to boot into Windows 10.  How can I get the dual-boot and get Windows 10 back?

When I turn on the system I get the following options:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Windows UEFI `bootmgfw.efi`
- Window Boot UEFI loader
- `EFI/Ubuntu/fwupx64.efi`
- `efi/ubuntumokmanager.efi`
- `efi/toshiba/boot/bootmgfw.efi`
- Windows boot manger (on `/dev/sda2`)
- System setup

Selecting any windows option gives error. Given below is the error that I got when I selected Window Boot UEFI loader option

```
/EndEntire file path: /ACPI(a0341do,0) /PCI(2,1f)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,200800,820000,60466f299ba3e211,2,2)/File(\EFI\Boot)/File(bk.pbootx64.efi)/EndEntire
error:  cannot load image 
Press any key to continue....
```

[Boot info](http://paste2.org/Hgd2AHD3) from Boot-Repair.

Comment: What happens when you try to boot Windows?

Comment: When I turn on the system.  I get the following option 1. Ubuntu 2. Advanced optoins for ubuntu 3.Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi 4.Window Boot UEFI loader 5. EFI/Ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 6. efi/ubuntumokmanager.efi 7. efi/toshiba/boot/bootmgfw.efi 8. windows boot manger (on /dev/sda2) 9. System setup.  Selecting any windows option gives error.  I ran boot repair too. Here is the log [link](http:/paste2.org/Hgd2AHD3)

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/809016/edit) your question to include those details, and also the error you get when you try to boot Windows.

Comment: Added the description as you requested

Comment: Can you boot Windows 10 now after running Boot-Repair?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Comment: @ Eduardo,  I am not sure if I made a selection for explicitly installing in UEFI mode.  I pretty much did the default installation along side windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is changing the secured Boot from Enabled to Disabled status in BIOS.  When I rebooted after this change I was able boot to windows 10.  Although it took little longer than normal.

Is there any risk in leaving it disabled?

Another thing that I cannot verify right now is if windows updates and other features will work correctly after this fiasco.  When I check for windows update.  Instead of showing the current time, it's showing the time of last windows update before ubuntu installation.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the windows disk to repair your installation, it would fix the windows boot problem but maybe break your Linux boot, use Linux rescue disk to reinstall Grub and you should be OK.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)